# I'm getting this error Car() takes no arguments can anybody helps me out what I'm doing wrong here?

Tags: python-3.x, class, constructor

```
class Car:
    c_mileage_units = "Mi"

    def __init__(self, color, miles):
        self.i_color = color
        self.i_mileage = miles

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        car1 = Car ("blue", 1000)
        print(car.i_color)
        print(car.i_mileage)
        print(car.c_mileage_units)
        print(Car.c_mileage_units)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Car() takes no arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most obvious issue is that the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block is indented to be within `Car` but it should be fully un-indented.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off, and the you first name the variable `car1` when you initialize it, but try to access it as `car` (without the 1).

```py
class Car:
    c_mileage_units = "Mi"

    def __init__(self, color, miles):
        self.i_color = color
        self.i_mileage = miles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    car = Car ("blue", 1000)
    print(car.i_color)
    print(car.i_mileage)
    print(car.c_mileage_units)
    print(Car.c_mileage_units)
```

This prints

> blue
> 1000
> Mi
> Mi

The error you posted ("Car() takes no arguments") does not happen with the code you posted.